# Adobe Illustrator Script to run every time I save

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm wondering if there is a way have a jsx script execute every time Illustrator saves changes to a file.
The idea here is that the script will check to make sure the artboard is not too large to work with (for reasons not worth getting into here, the limit would ideally be 120 inches).

I think the script would look something like this...

```
function onSave () {
    var sizemessage = "Could not save, Artboard too large.";
    var sizethresh = "120";
    var length = artboardRect[2] - artboardRect[0];
    var height = artboardRect[3] - artboardRect[1];
    if (length >= height) {
        var size = length;
    } else {
        var size = height;
    }
    if (size > sizethresh) {
        beep ()
        alert(sizemessage)
        DONOTSAVECHANGES
    } else {
        SAVECHANGES
    }
}
```

I look forward to learning more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code for event listner

```
app.app.notifiers.add("save", File(/*insert the path of your jsx file here*/));
```

Comment: Illustrator has a built in event listener?

Comment: Sorry, This is the first time I'm writing scripts for Illustrator. I'm not entirely sure how to get started creating this listener. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @Panopticon36 do you want me to write script.